# SSRS Column Chart (Bar Chart) needs to appear more clear

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS chart with a lot of values on the x axis. 
I have a requirement that the charts need to be exported to a pdf .

My Column/bar chart looks something like this :

[image]

If I have the chart any wider than this , the chart doesnt look good on the pdf , after 
 being exported to a pdf.

Please let me know if there is a way I can make the chart look clear to people reading it.
  One thing that I would like to do is make the chart into two charts , one appearing below the other
whenever there are more number of values on the x axis. But I do not know how I can achieve this ? Is 
this at all possible ? Please let me know if there is a way I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I've updated my answer to show how you can create multiple graphs inside a table.

---

To demonstrate this I wrote a sample dataset. The Sql is at the bottom in case anyone is interested.

[image: dataset view]

- I set up a parameter to set the amount of items I want on the graph.
  [image: parameter view]
- Then set up a calculated field on the dataset for the graph group
  [image: calculated field view]
- Set up a table with a single cell and row group using our calculated field
  [image: table view]
- Add a graph to the report
  [image: graph view]
- Drag the graph into the table, into the grouping we made.
  [image: graph table view]
- Then we can get multiple graphs based on our table row group
  [image: report view]

[image: report view2]

---

```
--Generate random dataset
--
declare @date datetime
declare @count int
set @count = 1
set @date = getdate()
declare @values table
(rowNumber int, value int, dateValue datetime)


while @count <= 250
begin

insert into @values(rowNumber, value, dateValue)
select @count, CAST(RAND() * 100 AS INT), @date

set @count = @count + 1
set @date = dateadd(day,-1,@date)
end

select * from @values
```

Comment: Yes please could you add more detail. Where do I need to set the Floor(Fields...) on my graph ? and I am not using a table here. I did not understand what you meant by "Then add table with a grow group using your new calculated field, and put your graph inside the row group in the table"

Comment: @PowerCoder Have you added a row number field to your dataset?

Comment: I just added a Row_Number() to my sql query (dataset) . AS Shown here .  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94312/4/0 Is that what you meant ?

Comment: I also added the calculated field expression =Floor(Fields!row_number.Value / 20)   to the dataset

Comment: Oh Sam ! You are just amazing ! That's exactly what I was looking for.               +1 and marked as answer. I know its not the same question , but now I see only a few bars in each group . Is there a way I can manually fix the size of bars.

Comment: @PowerCoder [This may help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seanboon/archive/2008/10/31/ssrs-and-microsoft-chart-control-chart-how-to-change-the-width-of-bars-and-columns.aspx)

Comment: Hey Sam ! Can you just see if you know how to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555227/how-to-include-an-ssrs-expression-and-an-indicator-in-the-same-cell

Answer (score 0):

To split the data, use a group based on a function to grab the first x rows and another to grab the rest after x. These become the two datasets for the charts. You can set a conditional hide on the second chart based on the number of rows in the second group. Hopefully, with the tweaks below you won't have to jump through these hoops.

- Change your horizontal axis properties to a custom or predefined    interval with the correct type (Category or Numbers/Dates). I can't tell which type your axis is based on your picture.
- Set a minimum and maximum font size for auto-fit.
- **Use an offset (located in Labels Properties)** to stagger your labels so that there is more space without having to stretch your width.
- Turn off wrapping in labels as this can cause them to become wider
- Depending on requirements hide minor tick marks.