# how to include an ssrs expression and an indicator in the same cell

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I would like to include an expression and an ssrs indicator based on the same expression in the same cell of a table.

I have tried doing the approach in the link shown :

```
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5f19834-ba37-410c-bb7e-179807dfefea/indicator-value-in-same-cell?forum=sqlreportingservices
```

but the borders for that cell become invisible when I preview the report.

Please let me know if there is any other good way to do this which doesnt effect the borders.

my expression looks like this :

```
=Sum(Fields!Total_Sales.Value)/Sum(Fields!Products.Value)*100
```

Comment: Exactly what expression you are using ???

Comment: something like this : =Sum(Fields!Total_Sales.Value)/Sum(Fields!Products.Value)*100

Comment: Have you tried adding the border to the textbox and the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the issue, is that you want to show the value of the expression and the indicator in the same cell. I struggled with a similar issue a while back but settled with the following basic workaround. See below:

First create two columns, one with the expression and another with the indicator. It should look something like this:

[image]

Then change the border style of both cells to none but only for the left and right border. This will make it appear as if the cells are one in the same. The end result will look like this:

[image]

Its not perfect, but this should solve your problem. I hope it helps!